# Bootstrap Carousel - Link in Caption

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am trying to create a tour of our hospital and can't seem to get the call to action buttons in the Bootstrap Carousel to function properly. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Below is the markup of one of the items.

To see what we have out now (links in captions aren't clickable) http://www.lebonheur.org/about-le-bonheur/experience-le-bonheur/hospital/ground-floor.dot

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="/images/photos/experience-le-bonheur/hospital-first/First1.jpg">
    <span class="carousel-caption row-fluid">
       <div class="span9 caption">
         <p>Le Bonheur Children’s Hospital opened an entire new facility in 2010. Le Bonheur is designed to be energy efficient and socially responsible. Le Bonheur is the fifth LEED-certified children’s hospital in the U.S.</p> 
        </div>

        <div class="span3 action">
            <a class="btn btn-large pull-right" href="http://lebonheur.org/our-services/emergency-medicine/">Emergency Medicine</a>      
        </div>
    </span>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing that `<span>` to a `<div>`?  That's enough to get it working for me.

Comment: DUH! - I totally missed that one. That totally worked. *GOLD STAR!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the bootstrap CSS doesn't allow an extra `<div>` within the caption.  Doing this hides any of your links inside.

You'd have to think of a workaround to get the styling back to how you want it, but if you remove these extra `<div>` tags then the links become clickable. e.g.:

```
<div class="item">
  <img src="/images/photos/experience-le-bonheur/hospital-first/First1.jpg">
  <span class="carousel-caption row-fluid">
   **REMOVE THIS-> <div class="span9 caption">
     <p>Le Bonheur Children’s Hospital opened an entire new facility in 2010. Le Bonheur is designed to be energy efficient and socially responsible. Le Bonheur is the fifth LEED-certified children’s hospital in the U.S.</p> 
    **REMOVE THIS-> </div>

    ** REMOVE THIS-> <div class="span3 action">
        <a class="btn btn-large pull-right" href="http://lebonheur.org/our-services/emergency-medicine/">Emergency Medicine</a>      
    **REMOVE THIS-> </div>
  </span>
```

So your new markup looks like this:

```
<div class="item">
   <img src="/images/photos/experience-le-bonheur/hospital-first/First1.jpg"/>
   <span class="carousel-caption row-fluid">
      <p>Le Bonheur Children’s Hospital opened an entire new facility in 2010. Le Bonheur is designed to be energy efficient and socially responsible. Le Bonheur is the fifth LEED-certified children’s hospital in the U.S.</p> 
      <a class="btn btn-large pull-right" href="http://lebonheur.org/our-services/emergency-medicine/">Emergency Medicine</a>
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `.carousel-indicators` masks caption area.
It can be simply verified using a color background for indicators.
So simply set any disired height value for `.carousel-indicators` less than `.carousel-caption` area.

This solves issue fo me:

```
.carousel-indicators{ 
    height: 16px; 
}
```